# A special kind of pseudo-garden eden states in cellular automata

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, symbolic-dynamics, cellular-automata, experimental-mathematics, limit-cycles

I'm currently investigating Wolfram's elementary cellular automata on finite grids with periodic boundary conditions, i.e. on $\mathbb{Z}/k$ for different $k$.

It is clear that for each rule $R$ and each state space $\Sigma_k = \{2^k\}$ there are three kinds of states:

- garden eden states $\alpha$, i.e. states without predecessor $\beta$ with $\Phi_R(\beta) = \alpha$
- periodic states $\omega$, i.e. states lying on a limit cycle
- transient states $\tau$, i.e. states lying on shortest trajectories going from some $\alpha$ to some $\omega$.

It turns out that there are limit cycles of which some but not all periodic states $\omega$ are "targets" of some garden eden state: their unique predecessor lies on the same limit cycle. Let's call these states $\gamma$ *pseudo-garden eden states* (without further reason).

I wonder if $\gamma$ states were found worth to be investigated. We know that garden eden states may be characterized by local patterns not reachable/producable by any predecessor $\beta$. **Might there be a similar characterization of pseudo-garden eden states?**

For some rules $R$ and numbers $k$ pseudo-garden eden states appear periodically, for others they come irregularly. In the following examples the **non**-$\gamma$ states – i.e. states where a transient meets the limit cycle – are marked with their index.

**Rule 26**

[image] [image] [image]

**Rule 73**

[image] [image] [image]

**Rule 110**

[image] [image] [image]

**Rule 18**

[image] [image] [image]

**Rule 45**

[image] [image]

Comment: Usually we say "orphan", not "kink", for patterns that do not appear in the image. As far as I understand your pseudo gardens of eden form a regular language for any 1d CA, in the sense that a single FSA describes them simultaneously for all cycle sizes $k$. Not sure what your exact question is though.

Comment: @VilleSalo: Can you please give me a reference to learn how PGE states form a regular language?

Comment: @VilleSalo: The question could be: which specific regular language (expression?) do they form? How do I find/construct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition is not very clear to me, but I'll try my best. Let $O \subset \{0, 1\}^*$ be the set of words (considered cyclic for the purpose of CA application) which lie on a limit cycle. Let $A \subset \{0, 1\}^*$ be the gardens of eden, and $T \subset \{0, 1\}^*$ the transients (i.e. complement of $O \cup A$).

Let $U \subset \{0, 1\}^*$ be the set of configurations that have a unique preimage (let's say we don't include $A$, doesn't really matter). As far as I understand, your $\gamma$s are the set $U \cap O$.

I don't know what you can say about $U \cap O$, you'd have to look on a rule-by-rule basis, as the ECA have nothing in common. I'll mention my tangentially related answer here, which studies numbers of preimages of $f^n(...00100...)$ in rule 110,  [The graph of Rule 110 and vertices degree](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/289286/the-graph-of-rule-110-and-vertices-degree/369370#369370)

What, I can say is the following:

- $A$ is a regular language. In fact, the de Bruijn representation of the rule gives a finite-state automaton for the language of the image subshift of the CA $f$ (i.e. for the finite words appearing in $f(\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{Z}}) \subset \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{Z}}$). You can make it check for a periodic preimage by making it remember the beginning of the word and checking consistency at the end, it's a simple exercise.
- $O$ is not always regular, for example it's not regular for rule 90, see
  [Periodic configurations for elementary cellular automata](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/198982/periodic-configurations-for-elementary-cellular-automata/301968#301968) . You would have to look at this on a rule-by-rule basis.
- $T$ is just the complement of the disjoint union $A \dot\cup O$, so it's regular iff $O$ is.
- $U$ is regular. The proof is similar as for $A$. The general statement is that anything you can write with a first-order formula gives you a regular language. I explain with $U$. The set $U$ consists of $x$ satisfying
  $$\exists y: f(y) = x \wedge \forall z: (f(z) = x \implies z = y)$$
  Pull out quantifiers to get $\exists y: \forall z:  f(y) = x \wedge (f(z) = x \implies z = y)$. Observe that like the automaton for $A$ we can write an automaton that accepts triples $(x, y, z) \in (\{0,1\}^3)^*$, thought of as periodic words, such that the formula above holds, i.e. $f(y) = x \wedge (f(z) = x \implies z = y)$. Now, we do quantifier elimination. To eliminate $\exists$ on one layer is just symbol projection, and NFA are clearly closed under that. To eliminate $\forall$, use duality (complement with subset construction, eliminate $\exists$, complement back).

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot.